# How do I handle the newline, and separator spacing in c?

Tags: c, token, lexer

[image]

The actual text file is just random stuff to test the lex and parse. The pic above is the result, the console is giving me during runtime. In the green it is calling an Identifier when it should be a newline or delim, so nothing should be needed. In the red it is not recognizing the separator, and in the yellow its not reading the something.something at all. I'm assuming it has something to do with with the previous c; not being seperated right.

So my question is how do I properly separate the tokens, and recognize the newline, or what am I doing wrong. Below is the code that I am using to do the separating and tokenizing.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE    1024

// Returns 'true' if the character is a DELIMITER.
bool isDelimiter(char ch)
{
    if (isspace (ch))
        return (true);
    return (false);
}

// Returns 'true' if the character is a SEPERATOR.
bool isSeperator(char str)
{
    if (str == ',' || str == ';' || str == '>' ||
        str == '<' || str == '(' || str == ')' || str == '[' || str == ']' || 
        str == '{' || str == '}' || str == '.' )
        return (true);
    return (false);
}

// Returns 'true' if the character is an OPERATOR.
bool isOperator(char ch)
{
    if (ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '*' ||
        ch == '/' || ch == '>' || ch == '<' ||
        ch == '=')
        return (true);
    return (false);
}

// Returns 'true' if the string is a VALID IDENTIFIER.
bool validIdentifier(char* str)
{
    if (str[0] == '0' || str[0] == '1' || str[0] == '2' ||
        str[0] == '3' || str[0] == '4' || str[0] == '5' ||
        str[0] == '6' || str[0] == '7' || str[0] == '8' ||
        str[0] == '9' )
        return (false);
    return (true);
}

// Returns 'true' if the string is a KEYWORD.
bool isKeyword(char* str)
{
    if (!strcmp(str, "if") || !strcmp(str, "else") ||
        !strcmp(str, "while") || !strcmp(str, "do") ||
        !strcmp(str, "break") || !strcmp(str, "elem") ||
        !strcmp(str, "lout") || !strcmp(str, "file") ||
        !strcmp(str, "console") || !strcmp(str, "read") ||
        !strcmp(str, "write") || !strcmp(str, "mark") ||
        !strcmp(str, "emblemnize") || !strcmp(str, "lin") ||
        !strcmp(str, "send") || !strcmp(str, "dint") ||
        !strcmp(str, "continue") || !strcmp(str, "int")
        || !strcmp(str, "double") || !strcmp(str, "float")
        || !strcmp(str, "return") || !strcmp(str, "char")
        || !strcmp(str, "case") || !strcmp(str, "char")
        || !strcmp(str, "sizeof") || !strcmp(str, "long")
        || !strcmp(str, "short") || !strcmp(str, "typedef")
        || !strcmp(str, "switch") || !strcmp(str, "unsigned")
        || !strcmp(str, "void") || !strcmp(str, "static")
        || !strcmp(str, "struct") || !strcmp(str, "goto"))
        return (true);
    return (false);
}

// Returns 'true' if the string is an INTEGER.
bool isInteger(char* str)
{
    int i, len = strlen(str);

    if (len == 0)
        return (false);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (str[i] != '0' && str[i] != '1' && str[i] != '2'
            && str[i] != '3' && str[i] != '4' && str[i] != '5'
            && str[i] != '6' && str[i] != '7' && str[i] != '8'
            && str[i] != '9' || (str[i] == '-' && i > 0))
            return (false);
    }
    return (true);
}

// Returns 'true' if the string is a REAL NUMBER.
bool isRealNumber(char* str)
{
    int i, len = strlen(str);
    bool hasDecimal = false;

    if (len == 0)
        return (false);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (str[i] != '0' && str[i] != '1' && str[i] != '2'
            && str[i] != '3' && str[i] != '4' && str[i] != '5'
            && str[i] != '6' && str[i] != '7' && str[i] != '8'
            && str[i] != '9' && str[i] != '.' ||
            (str[i] == '-' && i > 0))
            return (false);
        if (str[i] == '.')
            hasDecimal = true;
    }
    return (hasDecimal);
}

// Extracts the SUBSTRING.
char* subString(char* str, int left, int right)
{
    int i;
    char* subStr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (right - left + 2));

    for (i = left; i <= right; i++)
        subStr[i - left] = str[i];
    subStr[right - left + 1] = '\0';
    return (subStr);
}

// Parsing the input STRING.
void parse(char* str)
{
    int left = 0, right = 0;
    int len = strlen(str);

    while (right <= len && left <= right)
    {
        if (isDelimiter(str[right]) == false)
            right++;


        if (isDelimiter(str[right]) == true && left == right)
        {
            if (isOperator(str[right]) == true)
                printf("'%c' IS A OPERATOR\n", str[right]);

            right++;
            left = right;
        }

        if (isDelimiter(str[right]) == true && left == right)
        {
            if (isDelimiter(str[right]) == true)
                printf("'%c' IS A DELIMITER\n", str[right]);

            right++;
            left = right;
        }

        if (isSeperator(str[right]) == true && left == right)
        {
            //needed to recognize seperator to the right
            if (isSeperator(str[right]) == true)
                printf("'%c' IS A SEPERATOR\n", str[right]);

            right++;
            left = right;

            //needed to recognize seperator to the left
            if (isSeperator(str[right]) == true)
                printf("'%c' IS A SEPERATOR\n", str[left]);

            right++;
            left = right;
        }
        else if (isDelimiter(str[right]) == true && left != right
            || (right == len && left != right)) {
            char* subStr = subString(str, left, right - 1);

            if (isKeyword(subStr) == true)
                printf("'%s' IS A KEYWORD\n", subStr);

            else if (isInteger(subStr) == true)
                printf("'%s' IS AN INTEGER\n", subStr);

            else if (isRealNumber(subStr) == true)
                printf("'%s' IS A REAL NUMBER\n", subStr);

            else if (validIdentifier(subStr) == true
                && isDelimiter(str[right - 1]) == false
                && isSeperator(str[right - 1]) == false)
                printf("'%s' IS A VALID IDENTIFIER\n", subStr);

            left = right;
        }
    }
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv)
{

    /* declare a file pointer */
    FILE    *file;
    char    *buffer;
    long    numbytes;

    /* open an existing file for reading */
    file = fopen("Text.txt", "r");

    /* quit if the file does not exist */
    if (file == NULL)
        return 1;

    /* Get the number of bytes */
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
    numbytes = ftell(file);

    /* reset the file position indicator to
    the beginning of the file */
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    /* grab sufficient memory for the
    buffer to hold the text */
    buffer = (char*)calloc(numbytes, sizeof(char));

    /* memory error */
    if (buffer == NULL)
        return 1;

    /* copy all the text into the buffer */
    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), numbytes, file);

    /* confirm we have read the file by
    outputing it to the console */
    printf("  The file called Text.txt contains this text  \n     \n %s             \n\n", buffer);

    parse(buffer); // calling the parse function
    fclose(file);

    /* free the memory we used for the buffer */
    free(buffer);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running it through a debugger and seeing what it is doing when you get the unexpected result?

Comment: Yes, There are no errors, or anything unusual in the output.

Comment: Can you provide the code for isDelimiter, is Seperator and isOperator?

Comment: Thought I would add the Identifier as well seeing as it had the delimiter in it.

Comment: Your 2nd and 3rd if statements in the while loop both have the same criteria. But the first one, will modify right before the next if statement is evaluated. Perhaps the first one is supposed to be isOperator and not isDelimiter? Also should the secnd, third and fourth statements not be in an if-else chain?

Comment: Updated the code. The bools are at the bottom.

Comment: Tried using the else ifs @Spoonless  but it end up cutting the separators off. It showed both together instead of separately.

Comment: You might find it a lot easier in the long run to change your code design to use a state machine instead of all those complicated mess of if statements. Or just use an existing lexer like "lex" or "flex"

Comment: I planned on it after awhile. Just trying to get the basic function of it down and learn some more on states.

Comment: Rolled post back to where it was once answers started to arrive.

Comment: Lol, thanks didnt think about people wanting to see the orig.

Comment: 1) The answer makes little sense with your later edit.  2) Posing text as text is more useful than only as a picture.  3) Posting a [mcve] is even better.

Comment: So i should go ahead and repost the entire code so people can replicate the problem? There isn't much more code left except the reading part

Comment: Adding true code like the missing `#includes, main(), isKeyword(), isRealNumber()` would not contradict the answer(s) and would add clarity to the post.  Posting the file contents, as text, helps too.  Posting the warnings you received on compilation would help too - Take time to read [mcve].

Comment: And changing `isDelimiter` also invalidates my answer too :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is your `isDelimiter` function isn't picking up all possible values. If you change it to use `isspace()` it will match on all forms of whitespace.

```
bool isDelimiter(char ch)
{
    if (isspace(ch))
        return (true);
    return (false);
}
```

As an example, here is a very simple state machine to give you an idea of what sort of thing I meant. It can be in either of one of two states - INSIDE_IDENTIFIER or OUTSIDE_IDENTIFIER - and it switches between those two states depending on what kind of character it is looking at.

```
#define OUTSIDE_IDENTIFIER (0)
#define INSIDE_IDENTIFIER (1)

void parse(char *str)
    {
    char *ch;
    int state=OUTSIDE_IDENTIFIER;
    char buffer[1000];
    char *pos=buffer;

    for(ch=str;*ch!='\0';ch++)
        {
        switch(state)
            {
        case INSIDE_IDENTIFIER:
            if(isOperator(*ch))
                {
                *pos='\0';
                printf("Identifier[%s]\n",buffer);
                printf("Operator[%c]\n",*ch);
                state=OUTSIDE_IDENTIFIER;
                }
            else if(isDelimiter(*ch))
                {
                *pos='\0';
                printf("Identifier[%s]\n",buffer);
                printf("Delimiter[%c]\n",*ch);
                state=OUTSIDE_IDENTIFIER;
                }
            else if(isspace(*ch))
                {
                *pos='\0';
                printf("Identifier[%s]\n",buffer);
                printf("Space[%d]\n",*ch);
                state=OUTSIDE_IDENTIFIER;
                }
            else
                {
                *pos=*ch;
                pos++;
                }
        break; 
        case OUTSIDE_IDENTIFIER:
        default:
            if(isOperator(*ch))
                {
                printf("Operator[%c]\n",*ch);
                }
            else if(isDelimiter(*ch))
                {
                printf("Delimiter[%c]\n",*ch);
                }
            else if(isSeperator(*ch))
                {
                printf("Seperator[%c]\n",*ch);
                }
            else
                {
                state = INSIDE_IDENTIFIER;
                pos=buffer;
                *pos=*ch;
                pos++;
                }
        break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It cleaned up some but left out the a; b; c;. Would the delimiter in the valid Identifier be the cause?

Comment: Yes. There's no reason why a delimiter as defined by your code would be in an identifier.

Comment: Did as you said and changed to isspace, pulled the delimiter true statement from the valid  Identifier, and pulled the delim from the else if from the bottom of Valid Ident. The a; b; c; are there again along with the something.something so that's good.   The valid identifier is still reading = as Ident instead of operator, separator still connected with a;

Comment: That's because `isOperator()` is only called in an impossible situation. In the sense that it only happens if the current character is a delimiter as well as an operator...

Comment: `isspace(ch)` is not well defined for negative values of `ch` - although I doubt OP's current input stream has negative values and so is not noticeable. `isspace((unsigned char) ch)` avoids that problem.

Comment: Defiantly works, the only issue left on it is that it doesn't pick up the semicolon or the period. And how would i cut all the extra white spaces? Would I put the real number and isIntegar in the outside?

Comment: For the white spaces all I had to do was leave the delimiter strings empty.

Comment: As I said, it's a very simple example of a state machine to give you an idea on how to go forward with this.